# How to route controllers without CRUD actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller with a number of actions:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
   def find
   end

   def break
   end

   def turn
   end
end
```

When I add it to my `routes.rb` file like so:

```
resources :tests
```

and execute the `rake routes` task I see the following extra rounds:

```
    tests GET    /tests(.:format)          tests#index
          POST   /tests(.:format)          tests#create
 new_test GET    /tests/new(.:format)      tests#new
edit_test GET    /tests/:id/edit(.:format) tests#edit
     test GET    /tests/:id(.:format)      tests#show
          PUT    /tests/:id(.:format)      tests#update
          DELETE /tests/:id(.:format)      tests#destroy
```

Obviously my controller doesn't have the above actions. So how do I tell Rails to avoid generating/expecting those routes?

Comment: If you don't want to generate those routes then don't add `resources :tests` to your routes file.

Comment: Yeah I could do that but I do wand to define collections and members. So I prefer to define resources.

Comment: Why do you want to define collections and members?

Comment: well please have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify actions you want to route like this:

```
resources :tests, except: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do 
  collection do 
    get 'find'
    get 'break'
    get 'turn'
  end 
end
```

Comment: This still generates routes for `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update` etc. He should have a look at [non-resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes).

Comment: It can be avoided simply using the 
`resources :tests, except: [:new, :create, :edit]` etc. if needed (wasn't asked for so I didn't include it to begin with).

Comment: That is a very strange workaround: generate all the resourceful routes, except all the resourceful routes.

Comment: Mischa, the OP asked for something else, he focused his question on this particular issue, it doesn't mean he doesn't use other actions.

Comment: No, he is **exactly** asking for that: "Obviously my controller doesn't have the above actions. So how do I tell Rails to avoid generating/expecting those routes?" He doesn't want the general CRUD routes. There is no use for `resources :tests` here.

Comment: You are right, I didn't saw the "avoid generating" part. I stand corrected :)

Comment: If you're going to do this, at least use `:only` instead of `:except`. @anonymousxxx, you forgot `index` and `show`.

Comment: @Mischa IMHO, yes this is a strange workaround, but still able to work, as the time when we will be adding one of the curd (e.g destroy) we do not need to add resources but simply remove it from the "except". oh I forgot that

Comment: @Mischa, I want rails to generate route methods like new_test_find which I will get by using `resources` and `collections`. If you know of a better way please share :)

Comment: @Arman `get '/tests/find', :to => 'tests#find', :as => :test_find`. With that you can use `test_find_path` and `test_find_url`.

Comment: Okay, that's better. Thanks @Mischa

Answer (score 49):

Just add an answer for future, simple ways of route without CRUD :

```
resources :tests, only: [] do 
  collection do 
    get 'find'
    match 'break'
    match 'turn'
  end 
end

# output of rake routes

find_tests GET /tests/find(.:format)  tests#find
break_tests     /tests/break(.:format) tests#break
turn_tests     /tests/turn(.:format)  tests#turn
```

or use `namespace` instead of `resources`

```
namespace :tests do
  get 'find'
  match 'break'
  match 'turn'
end

# output of rake routes

tests_find GET /tests/find(.:format)  tests#find
tests_break     /tests/break(.:format) tests#break
tests_turn     /tests/turn(.:format)  tests#turn
```

for Rails 4. (cause [match method has been deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5964) in rails 4.x or latest)

```
resources :tests, only: [] do 
  collection do 
    get 'find'
    get 'break'
    get 'turn'
  end 
end
```

use `namespace`

```
namespace :tests do
  get 'find'
  get 'break'
  get 'turn'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the restful routes, don't use `resources`, specify each path and action on it's own.

```
get '/tests/find' => 'tests#find'
post '/tests/break' => 'tests#break'
post '/tests/turn' => 'tests#turn'
```

And you specify params like so:

```
post '/tests/add/:id' => 'tests#add'
```