# Rails routing: resources with only custom actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, restful-architecture

I have a `NotificationsController`, in which I only have the action `clear`.

I'd like to access this action by doing POST /notifications/clear

So I wrote this in my router:

```
  resources :notifications, :only => [] do
    collection do
      post :clear
    end
  end
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this? I thought

```
  scope :notifications do
    post :clear
  end
```

would do it, but I have a `missing controller` error, because - I think - it looks for the `clear` controller.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using scope, you should add a controller looks like

```
scope :notifications, :controller => 'notifications' do
  post 'clear'
end
```

Or just use namespace

```
namespace :notifications do
  post 'clear'
end
```

Comment: And if I need both a collection do and a member do in it? I still need to define the `post '/:id/edit` manually?

Comment: In your case and use scope or namespace, yes (`get :edit, :path => '/:id/edit'`) . If you don't need manually you could use your wrote on your question. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/q/17465335/1297435

Comment: Yeah, I feel like the `:only => []` is the most explicit and less hacky solution. Thanks

Comment: I agree with @AugustinRiedinger, using only: [] looks way more cleaner for me, then you can use member and collection as usual

Answer (score 2):

1. I tried three combinations:

```rb
namespace :notifications do
  put :clear
end

scope :notifications, controller: :notifications do
  put :clear
end

resources :notifications, only: [] do
  collection do
    put :clear
  end
end
```

`rails routes:`

```
notifications_clear   PUT /notifications/clear(.:format)  notifications#clear
clear                 PUT /notifications/clear(.:format)  notifications#clear
clear_notifications   PUT /notifications/clear(.:format)  notifications#clear # I choose this
```

Because of the url helper `clear_notifications_*`, I will choose the 3rd combination.

---

2. Moreover, actually I want to nest these routes in a resource:

```rb
resources :users do
  namespace :notifications do
    put :clear
  end

  scope :notifications, controller: :notifications do
    put :clear
  end

  resources :notifications, only: [] do
    collection do
      put :clear
    end
  end
end
```

`rails routes:`

```
user_notifications_clear  PUT /users/:user_id/notifications/clear(.:format)  notifications/users#clear
user_clear                PUT /notifications/users/:user_id/clear(.:format)  notifications#clear
clear_user_notifications  PUT /users/:user_id/notifications/clear(.:format)  notifications#clear
```

Still better to use `resources` block with `only: []`.

---

P.S. I think it makes more sense by namespacing the notifications controller under users:

```
resources :users, module: :users do
  resources :notifications, only: [] do
    collection do
      put :clear
    end
  end
end
```

```
clear_user_notifications  PUT /users/:user_id/notifications/clear(.:format)  users/notifications#clear
```

Answer (score 1):

```
post "notifications/clear" => "notifications#clear"
```

Comment: Please consider explaining why your answer is correct, and what it means to do.

Comment: I want to group all the notification actions and to have a `method :action` in it, like resources does, but without the default actions that I don't use.