# Rails: routing to pages that don't involve a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I've been told the routes.rb file I've put together looks like it was coded in a panic (it was coded in a panic).

The Rails app I'm developing is an e-learning and not all pages involve quizzing a database.

How do I go about including those pages? Do I NOT use routes at all? Or should pages be a resource? I'm a bit lost about this.

The tutorials all seem to focus on the RESTful interactions and not on the behaviour of the site in general.

Here's my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

root :to => 'home#index'
get "elearning" => "home#elearning"
get "howitworks" => "home#howitworks"
get "leadershipstyles" => "home#leadershipstyles" 
get "whattypeofleader" => "home#whattypeofleader"
get "showmetheskills" => "home#showmetheskills"
get "safeguarding" => "home#safeguarding"
get "toolsforthejob" => "home#toolsforthejob"
get "whatnext" => "home#whatnext"
get "congratulations" => "home#congratulations"
get "teamwork" => "home#teamwork"
get "presentation" => "home#presentation"
get "planning" => "home#planning"
get "communication" => "home#communication"
# get "newjournal" => "posts#new"

# get "profile" => 'users#show'
# get "profile/edit" => 'users#edit'

resources :users do
    resources :posts
end
end
```

OK, so there's a few pages under the /home route. Is that the right way to go about it? If you could explain a better alternative, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'd turn them into a pages resource, add in a simple admin system and make the pages editable in the admin system.

Answer (score 0):

You can create resource page, for example.
It will deal with model, containing page content.

With such approach you will clean up your routes file

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465335/how-to-route-controllers-without-crud-actions)

```
resources :home, path:'', except: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do 
  collection do 
    get 'elearning'
    get 'howitworks'
    get 'whattypeofleader'
    ......
    ......
    get 'communication'
  end 
end
```

Comment: This will generate routes like `/homes/elearning`, where the asker has defined routes like `/elearning`.

Comment: updated with path: '' to remove /home/elearning and get only /elearning

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing named routes, and don't want to list all of the possible actions, you can do:

```
get ':action', controller: 'home'
```

which will route all unmatched requests matching this pattern to the `Home` controller. You'll want to put this towards the bottom in `routes.rb` so it doesn't intercept other requests.

Otherwise, you can do:

```
scope module: 'home' do
  get 'elearning'
  # ...
end
```

Or even:

```
scope module: 'home' do
  %w{ elearning howitworks etc }.each do |r|
    get r
  end
end
```

Comment: There's obviously some details about routing I don't yet understand. If you wouldn't mind explaining; why would your solution mean 'losing named routes' and what does that mean?

Comment: @moosefetcher, routes defined normally in `routes.rb` will generate a named route helper which can be used in other parts of your application (e.g., `link_to "E-learning", elearning_path`). The first example in my answer does the routing dynamically, so you wouldn't be able to use `elearning_path`, you would have to use something like `url_for(controller: 'home', action: 'elearning')`. This only applies to the first example here. For more on Rails routing, I strongly recommend http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, which I revisit all the time.

Comment: I have been directed to that page so often, I can't tell you. I'll give it yet another look, but the Rails methods (eg url_for) do just seem to come out of nowhere. Under which class is the url_for method listed in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a cool snippet of code I use with my static pages.

I set up a static page controller and all you need to do is in there put the name of the page.
Then under the static page view folder you add a file with that name and in routes.rb all you have to do is

```
StaticPagesController.action_methods.each do |action|
  get "/#{action}", to: "static_pages##{action}", as: "#{action}"
end
```

This iterates over the controller you get and creates the routes for you.

If you want to see an example of this you can check out this simple [blogger](https://github.com/Salinn/blogger) that I did with it

The [Controller](https://github.com/Salinn/blogger/blob/master/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb)

The [View](https://github.com/Salinn/blogger/tree/master/app/views/static_pages)

The [Routes](https://github.com/Salinn/blogger/blob/master/config/routes.rb)

Hope that helps!